# Xcode 4.3.3 and LevelHelper Template

Tags: xcode, templates, cocos2d-iphone

I downloaded the [Xcode 4 template for LevelHelper](http://www.levelhelper.org/app/Downloads/Cocos2dBox2dXCode4Template.zip) and installed it to /Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v2.x/ and tried to run it through Xcode. When I try to create a project using the template, [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvnlZ.jpg). Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Templates are no longer needed and they actually never where

Please follow the step by step guide from here

http://www.levelhelper.org/app/documentation/DocumentationCocos2d/index.htm

Why do you ask for help on stackoverflow when LevelHelper has a dedicated support forum? Next time you want support please use the levelhelper forum or contact form or you may find yourself waithing for an answer that will never come. You were lucky that i found out about your question